# How to change the include_path Zend frame work in linux cpanel?

Tags: zend-framework, cpanel

i have domain in linux server with cpanel, i have copied the frame work to Public_html how  do i  change the include_path now to start this  frame work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your project root, edit ./public/index.php:

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
    '/path/to/folder/that/contains/Zend'
)));
```

This is the section you wish to update. Notice that you want to include the FOLDER that contains Zend, not the folder its self. I'd create a folder such as 'GlobalLib' in PublicHTML and place it there.